# How to display posts from a single category within a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I am trying to list only the posts from a single category of my custom taxonomy.

I have created a custom post type called "Inventory"
and a custom taxonomy called "Inventory Category".

I then created a number of categories using the "Inventory Category" taxonomy.

I would now like to display the posts from only a single category. fyi, this is not for display on the taxonomy.php page, that is all set up and working fine.  This loop will be called on other pages.

This is the code I have so far, it returns ALL posts from the "Inventory Category" taxonomy rather than just those in the category "bulk racks".

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'inventory', 'inventory-category' => 'bulk-racks' ) );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is how i created the custom post type & taxonomy:

```
/* --- Create Inventory Custom Post Type --- */
add_action('init', 'inventory_register');

function inventory_register() {
$args = array(
    'label' => __('Inventory'),
    'singular_label' => __('Inventory'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions','custom-fields')
);

register_post_type( 'inventory' , $args );
}

/* --- Register Custom Taxonomy for Inventory Lists --- */ 
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_taxonomies', 0 );

function register_my_taxonomies() {

register_taxonomy(
    'division',
    array( 'inventory' ),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Inventory Category' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Inventory Categories' ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        ),
    )
);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your looking for something like this

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'inventory',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'inventory-category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 
                    'bulk-racks' 
                )
            )
        )       
    );
    query_posts( $args ); while ( have_posts() ): the_post();

    // do stuff here
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Heres how to properly register a post type according to the [WordPress Codex page on post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and how to [register taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

Comment: Thanks for the reply VicePrez, but that is not returning anything at all for me.  Could the problem be with how I created the custom posts & taxonomies?

Comment: maybe, maybe not. check that your using their slugs and not actual names. Post up a link of your query, and how you registered your taxonomy and post type on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com), so others and myself can see whats going on.

Comment: you've called your taxonomy "division" not "inventory-category".

Comment: @maikunari please visit the links above so you can edit your code according to the WordPress Codex.

Comment: Aha!!  Thanks very much!!  It sure helps to have an extra set of eyes.  Very much appreciated, it works fine now.

Comment: To take this to the next level, is it possible to call these using shortcodes?  for example [inventory-category="bulk-racks"]?

Comment: @maikunari Glad it worked out for you. yea let me see what I can work out, are you trying to use a shortcode to query posts in that taxonomy?

Comment: @maikunari heres a [link](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-shortcode-display-the-loop) to using querys and shortcodes. Make sure you test it out thoroughly on you development site, before putting it on production (i.e. pagination and conditional tags remain intact). You can modify the code to your liking. Let me know how it works out.